# Spatial Index for Intersects

Tags: entity-framework, indexing, azure-sql-database, geospatial, spatial-index

I'm using SQL Azure and Entity Framework 6 and need to find which of 5000 areas (polygons) intersects with a point.

My code looks a bit like this

```
List<object> res = context.Areas
                .Where(a => a.Polygon.Intersects(usersLoction))
                .ToList();
```

and this translates into SQL that looks a bit like this

```
SELECT *
FROM Areas a
WHERE a.Polygon.STIntersects(0xE6100000010CBD14289E87AA4A403CACC9610DEB18C0) = 1
```

Performance on this query is absymal, taking 7+ seconds to search through 5000 areas on SQL Azure. The polygons are generally circuilar.

I'm not a specialist in this area but so far I've worked out that one can create a spatial index that will pre-filter the results set before a complete intersect check in performed on the area. I think that this index would work really well in my case as the areas are generally quite simple and if SQL were to treat each polygon as a rectangle, it would filter down the results very well.

But after a couple of hours researching I've no idea how to create and use a spatial index in Azure.

Could some kind soul please provide the command to add the index that I need?

Comment: Is your question about Azure in particular or SQL Server in general?

Comment: Spatial indexes are supported on SQL Azure V12 just like on SQL Server. Please use the following link for reference. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934196.aspx

Comment: @Yuri Diomin. Just Azure.

Comment: @ckarst - thanks for that. Any tips on creating an index that will do the equivalent of creating a bounding rectangle around the area which the 4 points would be used as an index to match intersecting points?